# Can't manage the width of the submenu as the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created one menu in which one item has submenu. The width of the submenu is the whole screen width where the requirement is,. it should be according to parent element width.

I have tried doing display property changes but it didn't help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dropDown-nav, #submenu").mouseenter(function() {
    // console.log("mouse entered");
    $("#submenu").show();
  });

  $("#submenu, #dropDown-nav").mouseleave(function() {
    // console.log("mouse left");
    $("#submenu").hide();
  });

  $(".topnav a").click(function(event) {
    $("a").css('background-color', '#2F3942');
    $(".dropbtn").css('background-color', '#2F3942');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#E1E1E1');
    $("a").css('color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(".dropbtn").css('color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(this).css('color', '#2F3942');
  });

  $(".dropdown-content a").click(function(event) {
    $(".topnav a").css('background-color', '#2F3942');
    $(".dropbtn").css('background-color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(".topnav a").css('color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(".dropbtn").css('color', '#2F3942');
    $(this).css('color', '#2F3942');
  });

});

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
#mainNav {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0D5DB8;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 6em;
}


/* #mainNav_2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
} */


/* body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
} */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2F3942;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #E1E1E1;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.forMargin {
  margin-right: 15px;
}


/* 
    .topnav a:active{
        background-color: #E1E1E1;
        color: #2F3942; 
    } */


/* .active {
      background-color: #E1E1E1;
      color: #2F3942;
    } */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #E1E1E1;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #2F3942;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: E1E1E1;
  padding: 7px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #2F3942;
  color: E1E1E1;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    } */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a,
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-sm j" id="mainNav">
  <div class="col-4" id="mainNav_1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="mainNav_2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="mainNav_3">
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#A" class="forMargin">A</a>
  <a href="#B" class="forMargin">B</a>
  <a href="#C" class="forMargin">C</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="dropDown-nav" class="forMargin">D 
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="submenu">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

The requirement is to have submenu item size according to the parent. ( In this case if you hover and the portion you can see as #E1E1E1 colored)

Comment: I started doing from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp. It is simple but I ended up doing something else so I want to fix it.

Comment: So maybe best would be to restart or compare current version content with original ;-)

Comment: I know what the problem is. If I remove the bootstrap css and provide position:absolute in dropdown content then It is working fine. But I need the bootstrap css.